# Not getting radio buttons properly in post array

Tags: php, post, radio-button

I have block of code which is loaded while clicking a particular button through Ajax.

I have given each input a name like `txtname[]`, `country[]` and also `radiobtn[]`.

The problem is, when I am filling these 3 fields twice and selecting a radio button in the **second iteration** and then printing post array through `print_r($_POST);`

is showing the following results below:

`[txtname] => Array ( [0] => xyz[1] => abc)[country] => Array ( [0] => India[1] => United Kingdom ) [radiobtn] => Array ( [0] => true )`

It shouldn't show like:

> [txtname] => Array ( [0] => xyz[1] => abc)[country] => Array ( [0] => India[1] => United Kingdom ) **[radiobtn] => Array ( [0] => ""[1] => true)**

So how to go about knowing which iteration radio button is selected?
Any help appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio"  name="radiobtn[]" value="true">
<input  type="text" name="txtname[]" >
   <select name="country[]"> 
<option value="country" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
<option value="United States" >India </option> 
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
   </select>
```

Comment: give us some code to sniff xD

Comment: radio button with array doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well you are showing only one select, text and radio field. Then how you get multiple data in array on PHP Side . `[txtname] => Array ( [0] => xyz[1] => abc`. Atleast show full html.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj As i have mentioned in the question these fields are generated throgh ajax on a button click.And that is not an issue here,because it is displaying other field's value very well.

Comment: I think `array` is for multiple option, radio button should use `name="radiobtn"`

Comment: That is needed to understand as You getting two radio button data. And we yet to know what value other radio button held.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting two values from `radiobtn` which is of type `radio`. The radio button type is supposed to force the selection of only *one* item, therefore the `radiobtn[]` array you are trying to populate will *always* contain only one value, which is `true`. And that is correctly shown by the result:

```
[radiobtn] => Array ( [0] => true )
```

Your `radiobtn[]` array is overwritten at each iteration, leading to only the last result being stored in the `$_POST` global variable. Therefore the `[]` in `radiobtn[]` is pointless since there will never be more than one value.

For multiple selections you may want to take a look at `type="checkbox"` which can store multiple values for the same *name*. An example would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="btn[]" value="A">A</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="btn[]" value="B">B</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="btn[]" value="C">C</input>
```